# How can believe in the authenticity of the sirah and hadith?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, authenticity, seerah

Ramadan Kareem to everyone, firstly i wanted to ask some questions that has been bothering me for quite a while and i'm searching for an answer to it.

1. i came across some kind of a quora debate and someone said how can they be sure of the sirah of prophet mohamed and the hadiths?
   All that has been told about prophet muhammed peace and blessings be upon him are told by the sahaba, how can i prove that everything that was said about him during his journey and even before it is 100% authentic?
   How can i be sure that nothing was twisted in order to fit an agenda?
   Things that were said about him, his actions etc. is there non-muslim historians that confirmed any of the sirah and how it was told?
2. did prophet muhammed peace and blessings be upon him had access to any type or form scientific data around him? (i know he was illiterate)

Please keep in mind that i'm in no shape or form trying to insult or offend anyone by such question, i have been struggling with doubts for years and with searching for months i'm still to have answers for my questions. i need some clarfications in order to keep my mind at peace. keep in mind that i'm in a desprate need for answers

Comment: Instead of going to Quora and reading some random internet stranger's baseless assumptions about things that happened 14 centuries before his existence, go learn real sciences of Hadith. Learn how it is transmitted and how it is judged as being authentic.

Comment: Why should you give an answer or explanation or proof at all? Religion is a matter of believe. Beside this the qur'an itself was transmitted to us via sahabah so would you also look for a proof for its authenticity?

Comment: Would you before believing in the Quran ask whether non-Muslim historians agree with it? Obviously not! Our religion does not depend on non-Muslim expertise. We have our expert scholars of hadith Alhamdulillah.

Answer (score -1):

Assalamu alaikmum bro. 
It all comes down to the belief of the Holy Quran, as you, despite your own doubts, know the Quran to be unchanged since the day it was revealed. 
If a Hadith goes against anything the Quran says, we can dismiss it. 
If Hadith is in favour of the Quran, then you look into the authenticity of the Hadith. As you know there are 6 books of Hadith known to be authentic, because the research done for them were carried out thoroughly. If you are unsure about the 100% accuracy regarding these books, you should read into the biography and history of the person who collected the Hadith for example Bukhari. 
You will also find that some Hadith have various versions, but say the same thing, depending on who narrated it. 
You should also look into the history of the Arabs. These people were known to have brilliant memories, and were tasked to learn and teach their entire family, or tribal, history. They were also amazing poets and would know them all through memory. 
Furthermore you should look into the actual narrator themselves, for example Hadrat Aisha ra who was the beloved wife of the Holy Prophet. 
There are a lot of Hadith, but remember the ultimate word is of Allah and the Quran. 
Jazakallah bro.